# Access to parent's routes from nested navigation (rendered by component)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to access parent's routes form nested navigation rendered by a component?

Case 1 - Working good - Both RootStack's routes and RootTab's routes accessible from RootTab

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator({
  RootTab: { screen: RootTab },
  RootTwo: { screen: RootTwo },
});
const RootTab = TabNavigator({
  ChildStack: { screen: ChildStack }
});
const ChildStack = StackNavigator({
  UserScreen: { screen: UserScreen }
});
```

Case 2 - Working wrong - only RootTab's routes accessible from RootTab. No access to RootStack's routes

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator({
  RootTab: { screen: WrapperRootTab },
  RootTwo: { screen: RootTwo },
});
const RootTab = TabNavigator({
  ChildStack: { screen: ChildStack }
});
class WrapperRootTab extends React.Component{
  render(){return <RootTab/>}
}
const ChildStack = StackNavigator({
  UserScreen: { screen: UserScreen }
});
```

Is it possible to access RootStack's routes from RootTab's in the case 2?